# how do I set a value with square brackets using _.set() in Postman

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, postman

My question actually has two parts.

first of all I expected that I could simply set value by putting in my member name.  this works great for most cases.  However in my use case the Post body has a member requirement an array.  I must fill in a `settings[]` variable multiple times to have the fields properly separate.  in the UI it looks like this:

[image]

Well, I'd like to be able to dynamically set the body based on settings provided in an array.  Seems simple enough - simply build up the raw json request and drop it into the body as a global variable on the pre-request script.  I build up some code and come to learn that the square brackets are not detected.  I've tried escaping them with a backslash but they still do not appear.

simple POC:

```
postman.setGlobalVariable("genSettingsBody", (setting)=>{
    var bodyObj = { "mode": "raw",
    "raw": {} };
    _.set(bodyObj, "raw.settings\[\]", setting)
    _.set(bodyObj, "raw.settings}", "manual-entry")
    console.log("updates: "+JSON.stringify(bodyObj));
})
```

will result in:

`updates: {"mode":"raw","raw":{"settings":"read","settings}":"manual-entry"}}`

This is what I initially tried when determining that I could not stack multiple values.

```
postman.setGlobalVariable("genSettingsBody", (setting)=>{
    var bodyObj = { "mode": "raw",
    "raw": {} };
    _.set(bodyObj, "raw.settings\[\]", setting)
    _.set(bodyObj, "raw.settings[]", "manual-entry")
    console.log("updates: "+JSON.stringify(bodyObj));
})
```

will result in:

`updates: {"mode":"raw","raw":{"settings":"manual-entry"}}`

**So:**  How do I add in the square brackets on my script so that they're actually added onto the json object?

**and:** How can I append new members with the same name into the bodyObj?